# What can I do if I can't use chromium?

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I am trying to get a better web browser than the default one on raspbian. Chromium-inspector doesnt show up as a GUI when i install from apt-get. There is chromium-inspector and chromium-l10n. When i run `sudo apt-get install chromium-l10n` I get the following warning

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies: 
Chromium-l10n : Depends: chromium (>= 50.0.2661.94-1~deb8u1) but it is not installable
E: unable to correct problems you have held broken packages.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to install chromium? If so there is no binary available via apt-get. A search of this site will provide details on installing it from a 3rd party binary or from source.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to **install** something nicer I would recommend
Iceweasel which you can install by simply running

`sudo aptitude install iceweasel`

But if you want only things already on Raspbian there are 3 web browsers that come with Raspbian

netsurf: which you can use by using the command `netsurf`

dillo: which you can run with `dillo`

and Epiphany: which you can run with `epiphany`

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 1):

The web browser options in Raspbian do seem a bit sub par, although to be fair it is not a problem I give a lot of thought to since I use pis headless, sans remote desktop, and only plug in a monitor and fire up the GUI on occasion.

However, I believe [Ice Weasel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_software_rebranded_by_Debian) is there.  Note that the "rebranding and trademark issue" comes down to *the firefox logo*, so this is literally firefox "rebranded", since its licensing allows for such use of the source code.  It also sounds, in the current version of the linked article, like that whole problem is being resolved and in the near future Debian will replace "ice weasel" (get it?) with the "genuine fire fox".

So if you can tolerate firefox, there you go.

Part of the problem historically is that running full fledged contemporary file browsers on the pi was only marginally feasible -- again this may be a subjective bias of mine since I see the whole desktop that way -- since they just don't have the umph or RAM required.

The Pi 3 is probably a slightly different story (I don't have one), although doubling the RAM and adding $5 to the price tag would have made it much more so.

Comment: I run iceweasel on a couple of Pi 2s round here.  It occasionally gets slow but it's much better than epiphany (default on my raspbian) which struggles to load some pages, and renders long pages in chunks (a little annoying when viewing some documentation pages).

Comment: It seems web browsers are not minor projects, lol, particularly if you want to use mostly original parts.  Kind of like with cars, there's a limited number of players that can really sustain the effort.

Comment: Yes Ice weasel was a success. I agree with you on the extra RAM would have been better.